# Int to char array. How does it work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, int

```
int t[ ] = { 0x0203, 0x4 };
char *p=t;
printf(" *p = %d; *(p+1) = %d ",*p,*(p+1));
```

Why does *(p+1) always return 2, regardless of the second element in t?

Comment: The size of a character is not the same as the size of an integer. Thus, pointer arithmetic move a different amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char*` points a block that contains a `char` ie 8 bits,
an `int*` points a block that contains an `int` ie 32 bits.

Now, your original array is an `int`, stored blockwise in memory as:

```
t[0] = 0x 00 00 02 03  
t[1] = 0x 00 00 00 04  


-------------- ------ ------
|   03  | 02  |  00  | 00   |  <----- stored as little endian
------- ------ ------ ------
^
&t[0],p (both point to this same address)

------- ------ ------ ------
|  04  |  00  |  00  |  00  |
------- ------ ------ ------
^
&t[1]
```

but the pointer arithmatic is different for `char*` & an `int*`:

`char*++` advances by 8 bits because, well, the data type it represents (`char`) is 8 bits.
Similarly, `int*++` advances by 32 bits because, well, the data type it represents (`int`) is 32 bits.

So, in your case, this is what *p,*(p+1) point to:

```
-------------- ------ ------
|   03  | 02  |  00  | 00   |  <----- stored as little endian
------- ------ ------ ------
^       ^
p       p+1

------- ------ ------ ------
|  04  |  00  |  00  |  00  |
------- ------ ------ ------
^
&t[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're running this program on a [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) computer. This means your int array is stored in memory as bytes in the following order:

0x03 0x02 0x00 0x00 (first integer)
0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 (second integer)

Try to print out `*(p+i)` for p between 0 and 7, it should verify this.

Answer (score 1):

`*(p+1)` is a pointer to the second byte of the first int.

Integers are stored on most of the machines in little endian format.

So `0x0203` is stored as `03 02 00 00`, thats why you get `02` in return.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an effect of how pointer math is conducted on differing sizes of integers, as well as the endian-ness of your machine.

On a little-endian architecture (like whatever you're using - probably an Intel-esque processor) values are stored in memory with the least-significant byte first. So when you declare a 64-byte integer value 0x0202, it gets stored in memory thus:

```
0302 0000 0000 0000
```

By having p point to the same place as t, *p is now 0x03. However, doing arithmetic on pointers advances their values by the amount you ask for **times the size of the object**. In your case, t points to the beginning of 0x0203 and adding 1 to it actually advances its value by 1 **times** the size of an int, 8, making it point to 0x04.

Adding one to the value of p advances it by 1 **times** the size of a character, 1, making it point to the next byte in memory. That's the position that the 02 occupies.

If you want to see the 4, try this:

```
printf(" *p = %d; *(p+1) = %d ",*p,*(p+8));
```

If that doesn't work, either your machine or your compiler are sticking you with 32-bit integers and you should see the 04 with this:

```
printf(" *p = %d; *(p+1) = %d ",*p,*(p+4));
```